# How to install libc6 2.17 on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, package-management, dpkg, dependencies, versions

I am attempting to install the video editor [Lightworks](https://www.lwks.com/) using `dpkg`. When I try, it says `Errors occured when installing`. I used the graphical package installer instead, and it said that the dependency `libc6 (>= 2.17)` could not be resolved. I am using ubuntu 12.04.

Is there any way to get this package in 12.04, or am I stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you can see [libc6](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libc6&searchon=names&exact=1&suite=all&section=all) 2.15 is used in ubuntu 12.04, so you have to find and add a external repository, "sideload"/install it manually or compile it yourself if you need a newer version...

as ubuntu 12.04 is supported for just another year, i would suggest you to upgrade anyway to a newer (lts-)release! - if it is possible wait 2 months and get 16.04 lts (supported until 2021).